# Pass variable within a function of a service to parent component - Angular & D3.js

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, d3.js

Here is a [stackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-9kyoyt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.component.ts).

I have a d3.js service file that builds my `svg` layout. Its a force directed d3 graph that has nodes. Each node carries its own data.

I have extracted that data into an array, capturing the ids of the nodes when selected. In my example, to select a node and capture the ID a user needs to hold/press Ctrl then click on a node.

This is done in a d3 `.on` click function within my angular service file.

**Service.ts**

```
 export class DirectedGraphExperimentService {
    public idArray = []
 
    _update(_d3, svg, data): any {
 
 ...
 
 
     svg.selectAll('.node-wrapper').on('click', function () {
      if (_d3.event.ctrlKey) {
        d3.select(this).classed(
          'selected',
          !d3.select(this).classed('selected')
        );
        const selectedSize = svg.selectAll('.selected').size();
        if (selectedSize <= 2) {
          svg
            .selectAll('.selected')
            .selectAll('.nodeText')
            .style('fill', 'blue');
          this.idArray = _d3.selectAll('.selected').data();
          return this.idArray.filter((x) => x).map((d) => d.id);
        }
      }
    });
 
 
 ...
 
 
    }
 
 }
```

My global variable `this.idArray = []` does not update with the id strings therefore cant pass the array to the component like this `this.directedGraphExperimentService.idArray` its always `[]` empty.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DirectedGraphExperimentService } from './directed-graph-experiment.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'dge-directed-graph-experiment',
  template: `
  <style>
  .selected .nodeText{
    fill:red;
  }
  </style>
  <body>
  <button (click)="passValue()">Pass Value</button>
     <svg #svgId width="500" height="700"><g [zoomableOf]="svgId"></g></svg>
     </body>
  `,
})
export class DirectedGraphExperimentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('svgId') graphElement: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private directedGraphExperimentService: DirectedGraphExperimentService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  @Input()
  set data(data: any) {
    this.directedGraphExperimentService.update(
      data,
      this.graphElement.nativeElement
    );
  }

  passValue() {
    console.log(this.directedGraphExperimentService.idArray); // returns []
  }
}
```

I've also tried emitting an event with the value via the `<svg></svg>` container in the component template.

**Is there another way I can get the updated `this.array` values into the parent component? A way to subscribe to the value in the function?** Perhaps with a behaviourSubject from rxjs?

Here is a [stackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-9kyoyt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.component.ts). In this demo you will see I have added a button that I press to trigger the update to my component file, obviously its only passing the empty global variable on my service. To add to the array you will need to press Ctrl and click on a node, you will see in console the array filling up(max of 2 string).

Comment: Did you already put a log before `this.idArray = _d3.selectAll('.selected').data();`? Does it shows up?

Comment: As I am using the global var of this.idArray, it shows undefined initially as the global var cant be seen. If I initialise it locally its ok. Regardless of this, I still need to find a way to get this value out of the service file and into my component somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `this` reference to the service into a different variable.

When using `this` inside the callback `.on('click', function() { d3.select(this) })`, `this` refers to DOM element returned by d3. It does *not* refer to the service.

```
// no collision for the this pointer
const self = this;

svg.selectAll('.node-wrapper').on('click', function () {
      // ...

      // get data from node
      var functionLocalIdArray = _d3
        .selectAll('.selected')
        .style('fill', 'blue')
        .data();

      const filterId = functionLocalIdArray
        .filter((x) => x)
        .map((d) => d.id);
      // use `self` as a reference to the service
      self.idArray = functionLocalIdArray;

      // ...
  }
```

**Preserve `this`**

If you want `this` to reference your Angular service inside callbacks, you could use the arrow function `() => {}` instead of `function() {}`. Arrow functions do not have their own `this` binding.

But this will throw a d3 error in your code since you are using `this` for both:

1. Access to the DOM element when calling `d3.select(this).classed()`
2. Access to the service: `this.idArray`

So wrapping the service's `this` is the better option.

**Using RxJS `Subject` for Updates**

Use [RxJS's `Subject`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) to 'listen' to any updates in the selection.

Step 1: Turn your `idArray` into a `Subject`

```
export class DirectedGraphExperimentService {
    /** RxJS subject to listen for updates of the selection */
    idArray = new Subject<number[]>();
   
    // ... Rest of service

}
```

Step 2: Change selection assignment to `.next()`

```
// instead of self.idArray = functionLocalIdArray
self.idArray.next(functionLocalIdArray);
```

Step 3: Listen to the `Subject` in your component

```
export class DirectedGraphExperimentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('svgId') graphElement: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private directedGraphExperimentService: DirectedGraphExperimentService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // become and observer by subscribing to id selection updates
    this.directedGraphExperimentService.idArray.subscribe((newIdArray) => {
      console.log('new id array!');
      console.log(newIdArray);
    });
  }
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-cnuxaw?file=src/app/directed-graph-experiment.component.ts) is a StackBlitz fork of your project.

Comment: Very good. I went with the local storage approach, but can now see what I'm doing wrong above. Not sure I will change from local storage in this scenario yet... but regardless this is helpful. Thanks!

Comment:  Maybe it will help someone else. Really like your graph - nice project!